# What kills you: Voltage or Electric current?

Tags: electricity, voltage, electric-current

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What causes an electric shock - Current or Voltage?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36440/what-causes-an-electric-shock-current-or-voltage)

When someone gets electrocuted, what kills them; a high Voltage or a high Electric current, and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36440/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Fair enough, you may close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The voltage itself doesn't do anything, it's the electric current that a high voltage can produce what kills you. A high current can disipate a lot of energy in your body (human body has low conductivity), and literally burns you.

Comment: Yes but you will probably die of a heart attack, not burns, because the current disrupts the regulatory electrical impulses in your heart. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_shock).