# Can you die from a $250 \, \mathrm V$ broken cable?

Tags: electricity

I have a laptop power cable that is broken, my dad taped it so it is safe now.

I am just wondering: would it have killed me had I touched it?

If you could state your qualification/job to show you that you know what you are on about that would be great.

Edit: I see dozens of little wires inside it and its half exposed if that makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, of course, if a stranger on the internet says 'I'm a [insert profession]' that makes them completely reliable and truthful...

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36440/2451 and links therein.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about medicine.

Comment: You need to put a photo here. If the broken cable is on the mains side, I would be buying a new cable. If the cable has a transformer in it and the break is on the low voltage side, then it may be safe, depending on the output specifications.

Comment: But the short answer is: yes, most certainly you can die from a 250V cable. Moreover, it is extremely hard to resuscitate someone from a 250V shock by CPR alone and an automatic defibrillator is needed. 250V seems to be particularly nasty: much lower, and the shock is often not enough to disrupt the heart: much higher, then the shock stops the heart "cleanly" (i.e. without fibrillation) and, as long as there is no internal damage from currents "cooking" your internal organs, it is often fairly straightforward to resuscitate someone from, *e.g.* a 415V shock by CPR alone.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance And that is why Ground Fault Interruptors were invented.

Comment: @nephente: Ground fault interruptors won't do a thing for you when you touch both wires of a power line without being connected to the ground. To rely on them is foolish.

Comment: "my dad taped it so it is safe now" - depending on exactly how it's broken, how it was fixed and what kind of tape was used, it may not be safe at all. E.g. if the frayed wire causes electrical arcing it could melt through the tape, and potentially it could *still* kill you. Please buy a new power supply.

Answer (score 2):

It would be the current that would cause damage and assuming your laptop had a 3 amp fuse in the plug top then yes across you chest 10 - 20 milli amp can stop your heart. Electrical engieer

Comment: for the average shock on say the arm or leg how big would it be? 10-20 milli amps sounds pretty low, ths may be a rediculous question but is it possible for a static shock from a trampoline to kill you if it is to the chest?

Comment: It's almost impossible to give an answer for that unfortunatly it would vary greatly on things like on how good your comection is to the cable, how long it lasts, what part of you goes to earth, how fat you are makes a big difference belive it or not, as long as you are not earthed you can touch a live wire and not get a shock at all but i wouldn't recomend it unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: @RayKay A 10mA to 20mA shock is a highly potent shock indeed. If you lived then you certainly wouldn't be wanting another such shock any time soon.

Answer (score 1):

It depends which side of the transformer the cable is broken.

The cable from the mains outlet to the transformer carries 250V AC. If you are NOT well earthered, for example, you are on nylon carpet, or wearing rubber-soled shoes, then the electricity will not travel through you very well, and will get a severe shock. But if are well earthed, ie., there is a good channel for the electricity to travel, or if you are in water, the electricity will travel through you, and can stop your heart.

The cable from the transformer to your laptop carries only about 12V at much lower current, and is unlikely to cause serious injury.

Of course the cable could kill you in other ways, whether broken or not. You could trip over it and die from a head injury. You could get one of the broken ends caught in a factory machinery, and big dragged to a horrible death. Or you could spend time wondering how your cable broke, and not notice the approaching truck.

Comment: And how would a truck come inside his assuming that he is in his house.

Comment: Laptops are portable. He could be using it at a street cafe.

Comment: As an aside, the 12v cable actually carries a *higher* current - but this is not particularly relevant to the op's question.

Answer (score 1):

It won't kill you if you touched the side after the transformer, that is the side that connects your laptop. The transformer is the big black box.

However if you touched the side that is connected to the the Power Socket and were properly earthed you would have died assuming the current flowing from the the  power board was not limited by placing some kind of resistor (don't remember the exact term) as I have done in my own house on certain boards to prevent the situation from happening.

Maybe you are lucky you didn't touched the broken side as you would have still got a shock and even a little shock hurts... Believe me, I once actually put my finger in powerboard when I was young, I alive due to the fact I had rubber Sandals.

Actually this edit is to show you a image [image: This is something that can happen if you actaully are not killed by the shock.]

This is something that a small shock like some Milli amperes can do.

Comment: Apparently this image shows (a) an electrocuted hand that resulted from using a power tool, which would have had several amps of current (ie. not milli-amps), and (b) the skin on the arm was deliberately cut open,  to relieve pressure which would have damaged nerves and blood vessels. See http://enhs.umn.edu/current/2008studentwebsites/pubh6173/electrical_safety/effects.html

Comment: Sure. I know that but I am actually explaining how dangerous getting shocked is. So yeah, but still thanks for pointing that out and yeah thanks for the link I love the info given in that link. :D