# Which is responsible for electric shocks: voltage or current?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, voltage

What is really responsible for the feel of electric shocks?
Is it voltage or current or both  ?
explain me in detail

Comment: What is really responsible for the feel of being crushed by a falling anvil?  Is it gravity or the anvil?

Comment: The Ohm's law is as simple as an equation can be. There is no simpler law in whole physics. Your question indicates that you don't know this law. Study it. If all you can learn from physics is a single formula, this would be the one to learn. It may even save your life one day.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36440/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

The voltage is responsible for overcoming the resistivity of your skin. Once that occurs, current then flows, and the amount of current flow determines to large extent the lethality of the shock.

The peculiar sensation of the shock comes from the way in which those currents perturb the normal operation of the nerve fibers in your body.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it current or voltage that causes the sensation of an electric shock?

**Current** gives the electrical "shock" sensation, and it is current that can burn or cause heart fibrillation and death - [see ref.](https://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~p616/safety/fatal_current.html)

- **Current** is the rate of flow of electrons - coulombs/second.
- **Voltage** is the energy available to be delivered per coulomb - joules/coulomb. Voltage represents the amount of work that the electric potential can do on a coulomb of charge. $\Delta{V}=Ed=$ N-m/coul. The unit of the $E$ field is newtons/coulomb, which represents the force applied on a coulomb of charge. The smaller the distance the larger the force acting on the charge. Higher voltage exerts more force on each charge resulting in greater amounts of current flow against a resistance, $V=IR$.

The consciousness perceives sensation due to the reception of an impulse from the peripheral nerves.  Pressure, temperature, chemical stimulation, light, or the stretch of a nerve receptor, etc. causes the initiation of a wave of depolarization along the nerve known as an action potential. The action potential travels to the brain from the receptor, through axons and synapses, where this electrical stimulation is interpreted as a type of sensation according to the brain area where it arrives.

But, other stimuli besides the normal receptor-mediated action potential can stimulate or simulate an action potential.  These unnatural stimuli are perceived as sensations of various types, such as pain, tingling, burning... An example of unnatural stimulation of an action potential in the nerve itself includes direct trauma to the nerve, such as a blow to the "funny bone" in your elbow.

Likewise, an electrical current of sufficient magnitude can push nerves over the threshold level of depolarization, and do so for a large number of nerves, and thereby create an overwhelming signal to the brain. Normal action potentials produced by nerve receptors have a characteristic rhythm and are interpreted by the brain as a sensation of a particular type from that body part. But, if you touch the hot and neutral of a 120V wire, you will feel a buzzing sensation, which corresponds to the 60Hz cycling of the voltage. The greater the current flow, the stronger the sensation.  A current of .1 milliamps is perceivable, 10milliamps produces pain, and 100ma can produce death.

- If you are wearing rubber gloves (high resistance - megaohms), only a very low current flows through you at 120V.  If you grab hold of 2 wires inserted into a 120V AC receptacle with rubber gloves on, current flows, creating a displacement current through the dielectric of the rubber - which acts as a capacitor. But, with a low dielectric constant insulator like thick rubber gloves, the current is so small that you will feel no sensation.
- If you complete a 120v circuit with the back of your very dry hands (500,000-50,000 ohms - lower resistance), you will feel a shock, the characteristic buzzing of AC house current.
- If your hands are damp/sweaty (even lower resistance and higher current at 120V), and complete a circuit, you will feel a very strong sensation. If you grab both hot and neutral wires with your hand, it may cause your hand to contract, making it impossible to release by conscious control of your hand muscles - the electrical current can cause your muscles to spasm/contract.
- If you grab the two wires with two opposite hands, you will create a circuit going through your heart. With enough current through your heart, it may cause your heart to lose its natural rhythm, resulting in fibrillation and death if the heart is not given defibrillated, such as with an AED. House current may be especially dangerous because of its harmonic resonance to the heart rhythm.

In other words, Voltage is only electrical potential energy.  The key word is "Potential".  Unless current actually flows, no work is done, and no effect is produced.  Higher voltage corresponds to a higher amount of force being placed on charges, which enables charge to push through resistance to produce more current. Without current, the voltage produces no stimulation of the nerves and no "shock" sensation.